# Jquery slider function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I'm trying to get the "Tell a friend button" on [this page](http://gloucestercountykarate.com/?page_id=2) to return to its original position when the user clicks on "Close," but it does something different. It open slides out when you click on it and I want it to do the opposite when the user clicks on close.  The function is shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tell").click(function () {
        $("DIV#tellform").show("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 2000);
        $(".tell").hide("fade", {}, 1);
    });

    $(".closer").click(function () {
        $("DIV#tellform").show("slide", { direction: 'right' }, 0);
    });
});
```

And the HTML is shown below:

```
<div class="closer">
    <a href="#">X close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, tried that and it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed The function as shown bellow and it's now doing exactly what I want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".tell").click(function () {

      $("DIV#tellform").show("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 2000);

      $(".tell").hide("fade", {}, 1);

});

   $(".closer").click(function () {

      $("DIV#tellform").hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 2000);
      $(".tell").show("fade", {}, 1);

      });

  });



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("DIV#tellform").show("slideTo", { direction: 'right' }, 0);
```

to

```
$("DIV#tellform").show("slideTo", { direction: 'left' }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
$(".tell").click(function () {

    $(".tell").hide();
    $("#tellform").animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    }, 2000 );

});


$(".closer").click(function () {

    $("#tellform").animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    }, 2000, function(){
        $(".tell").show();
    });

});
```